# type *models.*** has no field or method

Tags: golang, golang-struct

package main

```
id := r.FormValue("id")
name := r.FormValue("vacancyName")
vacancysubtitle := r.FormValue("vacancysubtitle")
vacancymusthave := r.FormValue("vacancymusthave")
vacancyoffer := r.FormValue("vacancy-offer")
vacancyduties := r.FormValue("vacancyduties")
vacancydescription := r.FormValue("vacancydescription")


var vacancy = models.NewVacancy(models.Vacancy)
if id != "" {
    vacancy = vacancys[id]
    vacancy.Name = name
    vacancy.St = vacancysubtitle
    vacancy.Mh = vacancymusthave
    vacancy.Of = vacancyoffer
    vacancy.Vacancyduties = vacancyduties
    vacancy.Vacancydescription = vacancydescription
} else {
    id = GenerateId()
    vacancy := models.NewVacancy(id, name, vacancysubtitle, vacancymusthave, vacancyoffer, vacancyduties, vacancydescription)
    vacancys[id] = vacancy
}
```

Vacancy.go

```
package models

type Vacancy struct {
Id                  string
Name                string
St                  string
Mh                  string
Of                  string
Vacancyduties       string
Vacancydescription  string


}

func NewVacancy(idn,name,st,mh,of,vacancyduties,vacancydescription string) *Vacancy
return &Vacancy{idn, name, st, mh, of, vacancyduties, vacancydescription}
```

error

```
.\main.go:133:10: vacancy.Name undefined (type *models.Vacancy has no field or method Name)
.\main.go:134:10: vacancy.St undefined (type *models.Vacancy has no field or method St)

.\main.go:135:10: vacancy.Mh undefined (type *models.Vacancy has no field or method Mh)

.\main.go:136:10: vacancy.Of undefined (type *models.Vacancy has no field or method Of)

.\main.go:137:10: vacancy.Vacancyduties undefined (type *models.Vacancy has no field or method Vacancyduties)

.\main.go:138:10: vacancy.Vacancydescription undefined (type *models.Vacancy has no field or method Vacancydescription)
```

Comment: А вы можете поделиться задумкой того что происходит в main, и развернуто задать какой то вопрос? (например: "почему при выполнении main возникают такие ошибки?")

Comment: у меня есть форма, в неё POSTом прилетают значения, и создаю масив вакансий и наполняю их вакансиями с данной структуры, но нечего не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

первое: `func NewVacancy` выглядит как минимум странно, наверно лучше так, с фигурными скобками обрамляющими тело функции:

```
func NewVacancy(idn, name, st, mh, of, vacancyduties, vacancydescription string) *Vacancy {
    return &Vacancy{idn, name, st, mh, of, vacancyduties, vacancydescription}
}
```

второе: `var vacancy = models.NewVacancy(models.Vacancy)` здесь что происходит, объявление типа переменной или создание новой структуры? И зачем это все?
Пропустите этот шаг.

дальше: `vacancy = vacancys[id]` будет работать только если есть уверенность, что в списке (похож на карту, да?) уже есть такая запись. А если ее нет? Наличие непустого id ничего подобного не гарантирует. Выньте запись из карты корректно, с проверкой наличия такой записи:

```
vacancy, ok := vacancys[id]
if ok && vacancy != nil { // такая запись есть, и она даже не пустая
    // апдейтим существующую запись 
} else { // такой записи еще нет или она содержит nil
    // создаем новую запись
    id = GenerateId()
    vacancy = models.NewVacancy(id, name, vacancysubtitle, vacancymusthave, vacancyoffer, vacancyduties, vacancydescription)
    vacancys[id] = vacancy
}
```

теперь есть небольшой шанс что что-то будет работать